# Canceled creation of conda venv halfway through, now I can't find the packages that were installed?

Tags: anaconda, virtualenv, conda, python-venv

I was creating a new venv using a .yml file using the following command

```
conda env create -f micasense_conda_env.yml
```

About halfway through my internet cut out for a minute and so a bunch of packages got skipped. I decided I would just cancel the process, delete the half-made venv from the folder where conda usually stores them (Anaconda3\envs) and just restart the process from the beginning.

However, when I went to look for the files there was nothing in this folder. But these packages that were installed must be somewhere because I lost around 2GB or so of hard drive space. Does anyone know where I might find these, or how I might go about tracking them down?

Thanks!

Comment: have a look at `Anaconda3/pkgs`. Please do not delete/interact with things there manually, but use the `conda clean` command if you want to clean up.

Comment: Yup this seems to have freed up the lost space and then some :)